# How to perform vectorization in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Is it possible to vectorize these calculations in order to avoid using loop 'for'?

```
a=5; b=10;
vect=log([10:-1:1]+b);

for i=1:length(vect)
 new1=exp(-a*abs(vect(i)-vect));
 new_vect(i)=1/sum(new1);
end
```

Comment: Please consider accepting this and other helpful solutions posted on your questions by clicking on the hollow checkmarks next to them.

Answer (score 2):

See if this works for you -

```
new_vect = 1./sum(exp(-a*abs(bsxfun(@minus,vect,vect.'))))
```

Comment: I was typing this... You can equivalently sum over 1st dim; potentially faster

Comment: Hey, I've made you reach 20k! Congrats!! Now you have all the superpowers! :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks and thanks! :) Edited with that. Yeah the last superpower probably :)

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much! Now I'll try to understand how it works :)

Comment: Oh, not that difficult, just didn't know what "bsxfun" does. Thanks again!

Comment: @EvgeniiNikitin Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the hollow checkmark next to the question if it has solved your case as I also noticed  you didn't accept on your previous questions.